# Properties of $\mathbf{Cat}$

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the category of small categories.

(1) Is $\mathbf{Cat}$ complete?

(2) Is $\mathbf{Cat}$ cocomplete?

**Remark(Jan. 11, 2013)**
Of course, the question is implicitly asking for a proof if the answer is affirmative.
It's easy to see that $\mathbf{Cat}$ has products and equalizers.
Hence it is complete.
However, I'm not sure it is cocomplete.
Since it clearly has coproducts, the question is reduced to whether it has coequalizers or not.
Let $F, G \colon \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be functors.
Ittay Weiss wrote that a coequalizer is the quotient of $\mathcal{D}$ by the congruence generated by equating $F(X)$ with $G(X)$.
It is easy to define the congruence on $Ob(\mathcal{D})$ generated by equating $F(X)$ with $G(X)$.
However, I have no idea how to define the congruence on $Mor(\mathcal{D})$ generated by equating $F(X)$ with $G(X)$.

**Edit(Jan. 17, 2013)**
To the downvoters, why don't you reset your votes? The question is clearly important in category theory. I know you don't like me, but the question has nothing to do with your liking towards me. I'm saying this not because I care reps, but because the negative votes are sending wrong signals to the users.

Comment: (I'm voting to leave open.)

Comment: I noticed a tremendously distracting amount of chaff here, so I removed it. Makoto, if you feel like you have more to say, I recommend opening a dedicated chat room. If you something in particular to ask the community, I would say that you should make or find the appropriate meta post (I presume you know much about this). Don't clutter the main site with accusations that other questions had similar demonstrations of OP effort and yet did not get downvoted, or bickerings with the community, or whatnot.

Comment: @mixedmath Please explain why you deleted my reply to your comment above.

Comment: He *has* explained the deletion. Any further comments continuing to clutter the main site will be removed as well.

Comment: A rather detailed construction of coequalizers seems to be given here: Bednarzyk, Borzyszkowski, Pawlowski, [Concrete (co)constructions in the category of small categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.5522).

Comment: @Martin Thank you so much.

Comment: I noticed that someone serially upvoted for my questions and answers including this one.
While I appreciate them, I would like to point out that serial upvotes are automatically reversed by the system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$Cat$ is both small complete and small cocomplete. It is not large complete nor large cocomplete since it is not a poset.

The only non-trivial part of the proof of small completeness and small cocompleteness is the construction of coequalizers. An explicit, and rather elementary, construction of coequalizers is given in the article [generalized congruences; epis in Cat](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1999/n11/5-11abs.html), TAC 1999. The notion of coequalizer (as well as that of epi) in the category of small categories was proved to be non-elementary (in a precise logic theoretic meaning) by John Isbell in 1968 in the article "Epimorphisms and dominions III".

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the proof in Mac Lane?

Comment: The question is implicitly asking for a proof if the answer is affirmative.

Comment: I'm expecting someone will provide a bit more detailed proof than that. Regards,

Comment: You seem to forget that this is a Q&A site. Every question is supposed to be answered.

Comment: @MakotoKato CWM 2nd edition, page 112 exercise 5 asks you to prove that Cat is small-complete. It gives you all the tools you need in the preceding pages. You may prefer The Joy of Cats page 211 and following to get extra/different insights

Comment: @magma Dear Magma, It is easy to prove that equalizers exist in $\mathbf{Cat}$. However, it is not so easy to prove that coequalizers exist in $\mathbf{Cat}$. This is a point of the question.

Comment: This is a Q&A site.
Please provide a full answer. It's up to a reader whether he reads it all or skips details.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it is offensive. I'm not the only reader of an answer. People read it and can learn from it.

Comment: @MakotoKato Ittay Weiss indicated how you can find coequalizers in Cat in a comment above:If $F,G:C \to D$ are functors then a  coequalizer is the quotient of D by the congruence generated by equating F(x) with G(x).  This is very similar to what happens in Set. If you think that functors are essentially functions of morphisms and that categories are essentially collections of morphisms, your intuition should help you fill the gory details of the proof.

Comment: @IttayWeiss It was not a demand.
I said "Please", which meant "If you please".
You are perfectly free for not giving a full answer.

Comment: @magma Would you explain how we define the congruence on Hom(X, Y)?

Comment: I think it's obvious that the proof is not so easy nor straightforward.
Otherwise someone would have already provided a full answer.

Comment: Maybe all that could have done so decided not to.

Comment: Ittay: I commend your patience, and I upvoted your answer. I would like to add that at a Q&A site such as this one, there are any number of reasons why someone would or would not answer or help a question asker. For example, I would understand if you were to never help or answer a question from Makoto again, especially if he offends you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez "Maybe all that could have done so decided not to."
I'm sure there are many people who want to know the answer.

Comment: @mixedmath Please be aware that there may be many people who want to know answers to my questions.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "Constructing coequalizers is not hard,"
Unfortunately I don't think so.

Comment: @mixedmath "and I upvoted your answer."
Do you understand his answer?

Comment: @IttayWeiss "(a proof can be found in Mac Lane)".
As you may know by now, this is not correct.
A proof(of the existence of coequalizers) can be found in the paper Martin referred to.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "If F,G:C-->D are functors then a coequalizer is the quotient of D by the congruence generated by equating F(x) with g(x)."
This does not make sense unless you generalize the notion of a congruence on a category.
Please see the paper Martin referred to.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Please define the congruence generated by equating F(x) with G(x).

Comment: @magma "Ittay Weiss indicated how you can find coequalizers in Cat in a comment above"
You need to generalize the notion of a congruence on a category.
This is not trivial.
Please read the paper Martin referred to.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "Why should I?" Did you know the definition?

Comment: @Makoto Kato: To be fair: it seems to me that Mac Lane *sketches* everything needed to establish the existence of colimits in sections II.7 and II.8 of his book. Similar descriptions are given by Gabriel-Zisman in their book on calculus of fractions. I linked to that article in order to *calm down* the debate, not to provide you with a pretext to heaten it up again. I think insisting that Ittay Weiss was wrong or careless (implicit in your comments) is unnecessary. He gave a two-line answer to what initially was a three-line question, so it seems this aggressive tone is uncalled-for.

Comment: @MakotoKato you may find Awodey easier to follow. Please check: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/notes/ chapter 4, pages 73-78. Especially exercises 6-8 at the end too. If the exercises are too much for you, Awodey kindly provides answers here: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/hw/sol.pdf . Enjoy the weekend

Comment: @Martin As I wrote I had no idea how to define the congruence on Mor(D).
Many people seem to think this is trivial just because Ittay Weiss wrote as if it was so.
I strongly disagree with this tendency if it is the case.

Comment: @magma Dear Magma, Definition 4.12 of Awodey defines only a congruence on morphisms. This is not sufficient for constructing a coequalizer in *general*.

Comment: @Martin "To be fair: it seems to me that Mac Lane sketches everything needed to establish the existence of colimits in sections II.7 and II.8 of his book."
He defines a congruence only on morphisms.
This is not sufficient for constructing coequalizers.
We need a non-trivial idea to do it.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: 1) What happens if you interpret Objects = identity morphisms? 2) See also Gabriel Zisman, page 4.

Comment: @Martin "1) What happens if you interpret Objects = identity morphisms?"
I think Mac Lane's definition is still insufficient.
As for 2), I don't have an easy access to Gabriel Zisman.
I'm not a university student nor a teacher.

Comment: I have impression that most of you people here underestimated the problem.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: I agree, you are probably right about 1): one has to do more than Mac Lane does (as witnessed by the example 3.5 in the paper by Bednarczyk et al.). I don't know if this is helpful for you, but here are scans of the relevant passage from Gabriel-Zisman: [page 4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/18CJ6.png), [page 5](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4WS0M.png), I hope it is understandable without further context.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "So, I propose to attribute this long chain of comments to lack of precision on the meaning of congruence"
Are you implying that you knew the *correct* definition of the congruence in the first place?

Comment: @IttayWeiss "Instead of making endless remarks if you have another question why not ask it as a separate question?" I clearly stated my question in the title question. I don't have another question except unfortunately I don't think your answer is sufficient.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Please forgive me to ask you again.
Did you know the definition of the congruence when you wrote your answer for the title question?

Comment: @IttayWeiss This is not off topic. I'm asking you about your answer. By the way, please write my name correctly and remove a space between the first and the last names.
Otherwise I may not notice your comment for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7075/discussion-between-ittay-weiss-and-makoto-kato)

Comment: I chatted with Ittay Weiss.
He said he knew the definition of the congruence defined by the paper Martin referred to.
I asked him why he did not write it.
He said he referred to the wikipedia page which states the usual congruence on morphisms.
I said it's not sufficient.
He said it's sufficient when we consider Free(D).
I asked him why he did not mention Free(D).
He said that's because it's a standard notion in category theory.

Comment: Basically he was saying that he did know the proof of the paper and he meant it by his answer above and his comments(which were removed by himself), though I did not realize it at all.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg "I wonder why this "answer" has so many upvotes."
My guess is that it's *just* because they think he is more authoritative than me for some reasons. Unfortunately for them, it doesn't necessarily work at least in mathematics.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I edited my "answer" to the effect that Mac Lane contains a sketch of the proof and I explained what seems to be the source of the confusion, at least as I understand it.

Comment: For the record, there were 6 upvotes for the answer before the edits:
i.e. "Cat is both small complete and small cocomplete (a proof can be found in Mac Lane). It is not large complete nor large cocomplete since it is not a poset."

Comment: @IttayWeiss "Precisely what 'a quotient of D' means seems to be a source of confusion. Is it a quotient of a congruence on D or is it a quotient of Free(D) by a quotient containing all compositions in D? The answer is that it is the latter."

I think you need to define two equivalence relations.
Namely an equivalence relation on Ob(Free(D)) and an equivalence relation on Mor(Free(D)).
Right?

Comment: formally, the objects in a category are completely redundant as they can be encoded via the morphisms. Precisely for such constructions I find it easier to reduce the detail clutter and do everything on the morphisms alone.

Comment: @IttayWeiss　OK. So you only define an equivalence relation $\cong$ on $Mor(Free(D))$.
Let $F, G\colon C \rightarrow D$ be functors.
Let $f\colon x \rightarrow y$, $g\colon y \rightarrow z$ be composable morphisms of $D$.
Let us write $f;g$ instead of $g\circ f$.
Let $f_1;\cdots ;f_n$ and $g_1;\cdots ;g_m$ be morphisms of $Free(D)$.
How do you define $f_1;\cdots ;f_n \cong g_1;\cdots ;g_m$?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I'm trying to understand your answer.

Comment: @MakotoKato I added a detailed sketch of all of the details as I meant them to be carried out. I hope this makes everything clear.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Unfortunately I don't know your definition of the equivalence relation on Mor(Free(D)). I think most of the users don't either. Would you please define it for us?
I'm not asking the proof. I'm just asking the definition.

Comment: It is defined precisely, I gave all of the constructions in full detail: $x$ is equivalent to $y$ when there is $a$ such that $x=R(F(a))$ and $y=R(G(a))$. $R$ is the reduction functor and the meaning of $F(a)$ and $G(a)$ was also defined.

Comment: @IttayWeiss When I wrote the above comment, I was not aware of your edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "It is immediate that this is a congruence on F(Mor(D))."
Then the set of objects of the quotient category of F(Mor(D)) is the same as that of D.
I don't think the quotient category can't be a coequalizer of F and G in general if that is the case.

Comment: @MakotoKato you are absolutely correct! I forgot to quotient the objects first. I corrected my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @IttayWeiss Let $f\colon x \rightarrow y$ and $g\colon y \rightarrow z$ be morphisms of $D$.
Let $h = g\circ f$.
I think the path $fg$ and $h$ should be equivalent. Right?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Let $f\colon x \rightarrow y$ and $g\colon y\rightarrow z$ be morphisms of $D$.
Let $h = g\circ f$.
I think the paths $fg$ and $h$ should be equivalent.
However, they are not necessarily equivalent in your definition.

Comment: @Martin "I think insisting that Ittay Weiss was wrong or careless (implicit in your comments) is unnecessary. He gave a two-line answer to what initially was a three-line question, so it seems this aggressive tone is uncalled-for."
There is a saying "To err is human, to forgive, divine". I agree that to err is human. But I don't think it's divine to forgive. I make many mistakes. So I can easily forgive people's mistakes *as long as they admit those are mistakes*.

Comment: @MakotoKato There was a mistake in my definition of the composition in $F(Mor(B))$. It's not the monoid composition but the monoid composition followed by reduction. Otherwise the remark that $B$ embeds in $F(Mor(B))$ is false. I corrected it and please note that now $fg$ and $h$ as in your previous remark are identified.

Comment: @MakotoKato I'm very happy to admit what I learnt from this discussion: In the context of small categories the notion of congruence as commonly defined is unnatural. A more natural concept will be a suitable congruence on the set of morphisms rather than the individual hom sets. Interestingly, this shows precisely why coequalizers of functors between large categories are not guaranteed to exist. That is, the only congruence definable for a large category is on the hom sets since the 'set' of morphisms is too large.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: Yes, I acknowledged about 30 comments ago that you had a point, but since you insist, I'm happy to do so again. Nevertheless I still stand by the statement you quote which is as much addressing *the way you made your point* as *its content*. You were very lucky to have found such a patient and generous respondent as Ittay Weiss.

Comment: @Martin "Nevertheless I still stand by the statement you quote which is as much addressing the way you made your point as its content."

In short, I was trying to point out that his answer was not correct.
Do you think this was uncalled for?

Comment: @Makoto: No. Read my last comment again. Then read your third, fourth and sixth comment in this thread again. Then think about why someone might object to the *tone* of these comments. Please do not ping me again on this matter.

Comment: To Martin, I was asking him a bit more detailed explanation of his answer by those comments. I think there's no reason why this should be frowned upon.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "I corrected it and please note that now fg and h as in your previous remark are identified."

Could you explain why fg and h are identified?

Comment: @MakotoKato since $fg=h$ already holds in $F(Mor(D))$: to compute $f\circ g$ you first use the free monoid operation to get the string $(f, g)$ and then reduce, but reducing it gives $f\circ g$ as computed in $D$.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I meant by $fg$ the element of the free monoid $F(Mor(D))$ composed by $f$ and $g$.
In other words, it is the string $(f, g)$.
It is not the composition of the morphisms $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @MakotoKato The composition in $F(Mor(D))$ is defined in such a way that the category $D$ embeds in $F(Mor(D))$. $F(Mor(D))$ is *not* the a free monoid. It is viewed as a category where the composition is induced by the monoid operation followed by reduction.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "F(Mor(D)) is not a free monoid."

I'm confused.
You defined the free monoid F(S) on a set S.
Mor(D) is a set.

Comment: @MakotoKato look at the way the composition is defined to turn the set $F(Mor(B))$ into a category.

Comment: @IttayWeiss So the underlying set of $F(Mor(D))$ is the same as that of the free monoid on $Mor(D)$.
Hence the string $(f, g)$ is an element of $F(Mor(D))$.
Is $(f, g)$ equivalent to $h$?

Comment: @MakotoKato the composition in $F(Mor(D))$ of f and g is equal to h, due to the way the composition is *defined*.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Let $D$ be a category.
Let $F = G$ be the identity functor on $D$.
A coequalizer of $F$ and $G$ is isomorphic to $D$.
However, your construction of a coequalizer of $F$ and $G$ does not seem to be isomorphic to $D$ in general.

Comment: @MakotoKato I will have to look into it with some care but I'm not going to have time for a few days now.

Comment: @IttayWeiss You wrote: "I will have to look into it with some care but I'm not going to have time for a few days now."
You have answered 11 questions and asked one question in this site since you posted the above comment.
So I guess you have enough time to reconsider your construction of coequalizers in $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: @MakotoKato For the time being I abandon the construction since I don't have time right now to do it properly. Please refrain from pinging me on this or any subject. I would also appreciate it if you don't stalk my activity on the site nor scold me for not distributing my time according to your priorities.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "For the time being I abandon the construction since I don't have time right now to do it properly." You wrote a sketch proof is written in Mac Lane.
I have no idea why it would take such a long time if that is the case.

Comment: @MakotoKato I very explicitly asked you to not ping me about any topic. Pinging someone against explicit request not to is harassment. Please respect my request to never ping me again and stop harassing me.

Comment: @mixedmath You wrote: "Ittay: I commend your patience, and I upvoted your answer."
His answer was not correct.

Comment: @Makoto: I still commend his patience, and I've still upvoted his answer. I have no desire to interact with you in any way further (nor does Ittay, it would seem), and I have nothing more to say on the matter.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Next time you want to drag out a thread this long, please, get a (chat) room! You can always come back and post the result of the chat room conversation in a comment.

Comment: @MakotoKato: it has been requested in comments and flags that you stop demanding that others spend time working on your questions. All of the work done here is volunteer, and if you harass others, beside the possibility of suspension, fewer and fewer people will want to spend time on your questions.

Comment: @robjohn I did not demand others spend time working on my questions.

Comment: @robjohn As for the length of this thread, it would have been greatly shortened only if Ittay Weiss admitted his answer was not correct.

Comment: @MakotoKato: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272479/properties-of-mathbfcat/272483#comment624674_272483) you noted that someone had time to do other things, and implied that they therefore had time to work on your question. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272479/properties-of-mathbfcat/272483#comment625710_272483) you again implied that someone should have time to work on your question.

Comment: @robjohn Ittay Weiss wrote "I will have to look into it with some care but I'm not going to have time for a few days now." I didn't say he would have to look into it. I just pointed out that his answer was not correct.

Comment: @MakotoKato: "You have answered 11 questions and asked one question in this site since you posted the above comment. So I guess you have enough time to reconsider your construction of coequalizers in $\mathbf{Cat}$." By disagreeing that he would not have time to work on your question, you are implying that he should put your question before whatever other things he wants to do. Nothing in that answer is "just pointing out that his answer was not correct."

Comment: @robjohn You wrote: "Nothing in that answer is "just pointing out that his answer was not correct.""
I meant: I just pointed out that his answer was not correct *just before* he wrote:
"I will have to look into it with some care but I'm not going to have time for a few days now."
I did not imply he should look into it by "So I guess you have enough time to reconsider your construction of coequalizers in Cat."
It was a natural guess, not a demand.
I had no desire that he would look into it because I knew that there is not a sketch proof in Mac Lane.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: This exchange reminded me of my time in a grad school on the west coast with about 1/2 the students being international, many from Japan and china (I am from Europe). There are,  in the right light, endearing cultural differences; behavior right and good in one culture, but very questionable in others. The particular question asked is probably important to you. But more importantly, you also live in a community of mathematicians - people who might hire you, review your papers, and with some of which you have to work.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: (ctd.) Your English is impeccable; but I warmly suggest to learn to not alienate others too. Say, I would not blow my nose next to a traditional Japanese person; and similarly, it helps you to not to step on other's toes. I really mean only well as I've seen a talented compatriot of yours fail in my grad school, even though he shouldn't have; and apologize if this stepped on your toes.

Comment: @gnometorule Please let me explain just in case.
This long thread of comments was caused by Ittay Weiss's misunderstanding that the question was trivial. If he had admitted his mistake, the thread would have ended peacefully.

Comment: Just for the record (and Mr. Makoto my request for non-pinging from you is still in place), my comment from Jan 18th above start "I'm very happy to admit what I learnt from this discussion: In the context of small categories the notion of congruence as commonly defined is unnatural...". Mr. Makoto, I'm willing to accept that you did not have any malicious intentions. Regardless, I experienced your commenting conduct to be very demanding and very rude. I do not wish to discuss this any further so please continue to respect my no-pinging request.

Comment: @gnometorule Ittay Weiss did not admit that his proof was not correct.
He just wrote "I will have to look into it with some care but I'm not going to have time for a few days now".

Answer (score 11):

**Theorem.** The category $\mathsf{Cat}$ of small categories is complete and cocomplete.

*Proof*. If $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a small diagram of categories, then define their limit $C$ by $\mathrm{Ob}(C) = \mathrm{lim}_i \mathrm{Ob}(C_i)$ and $\mathrm{Mor}(C) = \mathrm{lim}_i \mathrm{Mor}(C_i)$, with the obvious source, target and identity maps induced by the ones of the $C_i$ and the functoriality of $\lim$. Similarily, if $f = (f_i) : (x_i) \to (y_i)$ and $g = (g_i) : (y_i) \to (z_i)$ are composable morphisms, define $g \circ f = (g_i \circ f_i)$. It is easy to verify that $C$ is, in fact, a category, and that the obvious projections $C \to C_i$ satisfy the universal property of a limit.

The construction of $\mathrm{colim}_i C_i$ is more subtle. Consider the functor $\mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Set}$, $C \mapsto \lim_i \hom(C_i,C)$. We want to show that it is representable, using Freyd's Representability Criterion (Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, Theorem V.6.3). We already know that $\mathsf{Cat}$ is complete, and the functor is obviously continuous. Therefore, it suffices to verify the solution set condition.

Consider the cardinal $\kappa = \aleph_0 \cdot \sum\limits_{i \in I} \# \mathrm{Mor}(C_i)$.
Let $S$ be the set (!) of all categories whose object and morphism sets *are* subsets of $\kappa$. Observe that every category with $\# \mathrm{Mor} \leq \kappa$ is isomorphic to some category in $S$.

Let $\{F_i : C_i \to C\}$ be a compatible family of functors. Define a subcategory $C' \subseteq C$ as follows. Objects are those of the form $F_i(x)$ with $x$ is an object of $C_i$ and $i \in I$. A morphism in $C'$ is a morphism in $C$ which can be factored as $y_0 \to y_1 \to \dotsc \to y_n$, where each $y_j \to y_{j+1}$ lies in the image of some $F_i$. We allow $n=0$, which corresponds to the identity morphism. Clearly, $C'$ is a subcategory of $C$, and each $F_i$ factors through $C'$. The family $\{C_i \to C'\}$ is still compatible since $C'$ is a subcategory of $C$. Now basic cardinal arithmetic gives us $\# \mathrm{Mor}(C') \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \kappa^n = \kappa$. Hence, $C'$ is isomorphic to some object in $S$ and we are done. $ ~~\square$

*Remark*. The same proof can be used to show that $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ is complete and cocomplete, where $T$ is an algebraic theory. But I don't think that $\mathsf{Cat}$ is algebraic, because the composition is only defined *partially*.

Perhaps $\mathrm{Mor} : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is monadic? A theorem of Linton (see *Coequalizers in categories of algebras*) says that $\mathsf{Mod}(T)$ is complete and cocomplete for every monad $T$ on $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: unfortunately Cat is not monadic over Set. You proof is a nice application of the Adjoint Functor Theorem that avoids the details of the direct constructions of coequalizers!

Comment: @IttayWeiss You know that the adjoint functor theorem is non-trivial while the quotient categories defined by Mac Lane Chapter II is not.

Comment: @ Makoto Kato, I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. Can you please explain how does it relate to my comment?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Before I explain, I would like to know if you agree with my comment or not. By the way, please don't place a space between the first and the last names of mine. If you do, I may not notice your comment to me.

Comment: @MakotoKato I can't agree with your comment since as I said I don't understand it. That is why I asked for explanation.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I meant that the adjoint functor theorem is non-trivial while the result(proposition 1) on the quotient categories in Mac Lane, Chapter II.8 is trivial. In case you don't have the book, it is about the existence of the quotient category with respect to a congruence on morphisms.

Comment: @MakotoKato yes, I am aware of the technical differences between these two results.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Do you agree that the adjoint functor theorem is non-trivial while the existence of the quotient categories in Mac Lane II.8 is trivial?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7090/discussion-between-ittay-weiss-and-makoto-kato)

Comment: Just read Mac Lane, it is not that hard. It starts with the observation that a complete category $C$ with a weakly initial set $S$ has an initial object (just take the limit of $S \to C$!). Applying this to the category of elements $\int F$ for a functor $F : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ gives Freyd's criterion for representability. And this is what I need in the proof, not the Adjoint Functor Theorem (which also follows by applying the observation to certain slice categories).

Answer (score 2):

Awodey goes into some detail on the construction of congruences, generators and coequalizers in Cat in chap. 4. Exercises 6-8 address the same matter. These exercises (and others) are solved here:

http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/hw/sol.pdf

Comment: Dear Magma, Thanks for your contribution.
Since some readers might miunderstand, please forgive me to state this again.
The Awodey's definition of a congruence is not sufficient for constructing a coequalizer in $\mathbf{Cat}$ in *general*.
The correct definition of the congruence is defined in the following artice.
Bednarzyk, Borzyszkowski, Pawlowski, Concrete (co)constructions in the category of small categories.http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.5522

Comment: In fact, the link only contains basic material about special(!) quotient categories also explained in the second chapter of Mac Lane's book. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Dear @MakotoKato I am not able to access the BBP article. If you consider that it has the correct definition of congruence, I would be very interested to see it. You could post it as an answer to your own question (this is a perfectly accepted practice) and I would be more than happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: @magma You can search for the BBP article by its title using Google. Then you will find a postscript file of it.
You can read it online, though you may not download it.

Comment: @MakotoKato got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the end of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168276/pullbacks-of-categories/168304#168304) very long an clumsy answer, I recall a very interesting general construction of lax, pseudo and strict (co)limits in $\mathbf{Cat}$, which I learned from Jean Benabou.

Comment: These constructions only give pseudo and lax, but not strict colimits.

Comment: @Martin, if you turn the cartesian morphisms to be identities, then you get strict colimits.

Answer (score 0):

That $\mathbf{Cat}$ is cocomplete, as a category enriched in itself, i.e. as a 2-category, is (3.74) of Kelly's [*Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory*](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html) (taking $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Cat}$). 
Of course this proof applies to far more than just $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: before that, Set is already complete/cocomplete, so small categories are complete